# how do i set a value for a hidden variable in symfony1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need to store login_id to hidden variable for storing it in the database. How do i store it? after login i store the login_id like this `$this->getUser()->setAttribute('client_id',$client_id);`
and i set up widget in my base class

```
 $this->setWidgets(array(
     'id'      => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
     'client_id'              => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array(),array('value'=>'3')),));
```

how can i access client's login_id in my base class or is there any other way to set login_id to a hidden variable? Please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in you action when you create the form:

```
$form = new MyForm();
$form->setDefault('client_id', $this->getUser()->getAttribute('client_id'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as luliandro said Or you can do it inside form

```
    $this->setWidgets(array(
         'id'      => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
         'client_id'              => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden()
     )); 
    $this->getWidget('client_id')->setDefault(3);
```

Comment: This is actually much nicer solution than setting it in action; especially if you're rendering the same form in many different actions.

Answer (score 0):

In your lib/form you can do this:

```
  $this->setWidgets(array(
        'example' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(array(), array()),
    ));
```

Have a nice day!

Gunnar

Answer (score 0):

Limi Jerin
I have a problem too.
This is my solution:
You can try:

```
  $this->setWidgets(array(
 'id'      => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
 'client_id'              => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
```

sfWidgetFormInputHidden not suport value default. But we can using ValidatorChoice set value:

```
$this->setValidators(array(
        'client_id' => new ValidatorChoice([
            'choices' => [3],
            'empty_value' => 3,
            'required' => FALSE,
    ])));
```

I have a example of my project:

```
    $this->widgetSchema['portal_id'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden([
        'default' => [sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('portal')],
        'is_hidden' => true,
    ]);
    $this->validatorSchema['portal_id'] = new sfValidatorChoice([
        'choices' => [sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('portal')],
        'empty_value' => sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('portal'),
        'required' => FALSE,
    ]);
```

Thanks for reading.